# which way is better?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing an E-Commerce website using React, Redux, the website shows some products, these products can be sorted or filtered by a selectbox with some options.

I have two options for filtering products:

1 - fetching products everytime from the server and doing a check in the fetch function for example:

```
products = products.filter(p =>
    options.find(o => p.categories.find(category=> category=== o))
);
```

2 - fetching products once then creating a reducer that filters products every time different option is selected

**Which one would be better in the term of best practice and performance??**

**UPDATE: fetch function**

```
const fetchProducts = (categories) => {
  fetch('products API')
    .then(res => {
      let { products } = res.data;

      if (!categories && categories.length > 0) {
        products = products.filter(p =>
          categories.find(category => p.categories.find(size => size === category))
        );
      }

      return dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
        payload: products
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Could not fetch products);
    });
};
```

Comment: getting products from server every time the input query changes makes more sense. filtering the whole data in client side is equal to fetching maybe hundreds or thousands of data (all available products) which can damage both server and UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the application you are building. If you are **handling a large dataset** then you should prefer **server-side filtering**.

The reason being that client-side filtering might result in a number of issues. For example, the client might show previously cached data to the user even though things on the server have been updated.

Also, you can implement techniques like **throttling and debouncing** to improve your application's efficiency.

In short, if your dataset is small, you can go on with client-side filtering. But to always be safe, I prefer server-side filtering.