# Javascript : How do I filter the data on the UI based without calling the API again and again using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

When user types in an input box and hit search button, I want to filter the data on the UI based i.e if the username starts with the entered text. I don't want to call the API again and again.

Using JavaScript Fetch API concept, I've tried to search by username but it is calling API on every search I made

This is what I've done

```
function searchData(){
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

    let data = document.getElementById("usersearch").value;

    //passing the username, user enters as a url to the showData function
    url = url+"?username="+`${data}`;
    showData(url);
}

function showData(url){

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>   {
        let out = '<h2 class = "mt-3 mb-3">Search Result</h2>';

        data.forEach(user =>{
            out += `
                <ul class = "mylist card">
                    <li id = "myli" class = "card-body text-primary pl-3"> ${user.name} </li>
                    <li class = "card-body text-secondary"> ${user.email} </li>
                    <li id = "myli2" class = "card-body text-info"><a href = "https://${user.website}"> ${user.website} </a></li>
                </ul>
            `;      


        })

       //Edit
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out;

    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error : ',err.message))
}

//Edit
<button class = "btn btn-secondary" id = "btn1" onclick = "searchData()">Search</button>
```

I don't want to call the API again and again or every click of search button

Edits :

I am calling searchData() method using onclick function

Comment: How are you calling `searchData` ?

Comment: I am calling searchData() using onclick function
<button class = "btn btn-secondary" id = "btn1" onclick = "searchData()">Search</button>

Comment: How do you display the 'out' content after you filled it?

Comment: @MaximeGirou document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out;

Comment: OK, you can check the snippet i made ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare two variables, one to store the entire user list and one to filter by your input and display.

Plus, it is more clear for you and the other devs when you seperate the fetch and the UI. So you must refactor showData() to seperate theses process.

So here the process =

1. Fetch all users and store them into a variable that will never change
2. To display them you use a second variable that will filter your result by your input
3. Each time you search , simply execute the searchData() function

   Here is a functional snippet based on what i explained

```js
let users = []; // user list
let usersFiltered = []; //user you display


// you wanna fetch ALL user without filter and store in your users variable

function fetchUsers() {
  let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      
      users = data;
      usersFiltered = users;
      showData();
    }).catch(err => console.log('Error : ', err.message));
}


// then this function only shows filtered users
function showData() {

  let out = '<h2 class = "mt-3 mb-3">Search Result</h2>';

  usersFiltered.forEach(user => {
    out += `
                <ul class = "mylist card">
                    <li id = "myli" class = "card-body text-primary pl-3"> ${user.name} </li>
                    <li class = "card-body text-secondary"> ${user.email} </li>
                    <li id = "myli2" class = "card-body text-info"><a href = "https://${user.website}"> ${user.website} </a></li>
                </ul>
            `;
  });

 document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = out;

}

  // the search data will filter your inputs
  function searchData() {


  let data = document.getElementById("usersearch").value;
  usersFiltered = users.filter(user => {
     // here i filter by name but you can implement what filter you want
    return user.name.includes(data);
  });
  
  showData();

}

 fetchUsers(); // to fetch users at the begening
```

```html
<input id="usersearch" type='text' />
<button class = "btn btn-secondary" id = "btn1" onclick = "searchData()">Search</button>
<div id="users"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Client-side filtering is never a good idea. As a general rule of thumb, you should prefer server-side filtering. **Hitting the API guarantees correct results while client-side filtering may not**. I have written a similar answer to this one.

Read here: [which way is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635870/which-way-is-better/57635909#57635909)